# How do I immediately load another page in JSP/Spring?

Tags: spring, jsp

I'm not very experienced in JSP.  I have an application, which uses the Spring framework, that does a search.  I show these results in a JSP page.

When the search returns just one item, I want to immediately jump to another page that shows information about that item.

Is this possible in JSP/Spring?  I've seen tags like:

```
<c:redirect url="/somePage.html"/>
```

That's from another JSP file.  What I want to do is (this is a naive bit of code)...

```
<c:when test="${cmd.totalResults = 1}">
    <c:redirect url="/loadItemInfo.html?id=someId"/>
</c:when>
```

Thanks in advance for your advice and help!  You can omit anything regarding the parameters involved; I can figure those out.  What I'm asking for is simply making this happen.

1. Page loads.
2. Page sees that there is only one result.
3. Page goes to the page for that result, which is what happens anyway when the user clicks that search result.  This saves a click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the number of items logic in your Spring controller not in the jsp file.

Inside your Spring controller you may have something like this:

```
if(items.size==1){
 //Query items[0] info
 return new ModelAndView("itemInfo",model);
}
else{
   return new ModelAndView("listOfItems",model);
}
```

Comment: This is some good insight.  This project is actually something I took over (hence the lack of knowledge of JSP), so I'll look into whether or not it gets to the controller-tier so I can check as you've stated.  I'm wary because I do notice that the previous dev is checking the result number from the JSP in a <c:choose> ... </c:choose> as I noted in my "sample code".   If I'm able to do it from the code, I'll mark your response as the answer.  ACTUALLY: you're totally right.  This is the way it SHOULD be done, and I believe I see how.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, this page is going to need to be rewritten a bit.  Currently, it only overrides referenceDate(..), which means that it's only doing GETs.  This sort of check belongs in a POST action, like in onSubmit(), yes?

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to show the page for a while and the redirect to another one? You won't be able to do this with a jsp tag. You need javascript.

```
document.location.href = '/path';
```

Comment: This looked like a good and quick fix, but it didn't work.  Here's what I did, in case you're still curious about what was tried: <c:when test="${cmd.totalResults = 1}">
 <script type="text/javascript">
  document.location.href = "/anotherPageToLoad.html" />
 </script>
</c:when>

Comment: @Danny I was giving the idea in case you need to show the page and then redirect. Of course you have to add it in a jsp tag to execute it only when there's only one result. If you want to show the page for X seconds and then redirect you should include it in a timer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460474/how-to-set-a-timer-in-javascript

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Showing the page for a certain amount of time isn't necessary; from the user's point of view, I just want them to click "Search" and then see the information for the single item (if it's the only item returned).  Your input might still be useful to searchers and I appreciate your following up, so +1 for you.