# Is there any way to get and show status of a running server process at a web page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

What I have is a process on the server that runs and takes a lot of time. It essentially builds some data tables that are displayed on a page on post-back.

What I want is a way to log progress somewhere while the server process is running and report that on the page I am looking at before it is refreshed with the completed data.

Is this even possible? The best way I can think of to do this is to log progress to a file on the server and periodically read the file contents via Ajax/Javascript, but this seems like a kludge.

Maybe this is possible using multiple pages or threads. I'm not sure.

Any suggestions?

**Edit:**
The main goal is to show a progress bar of some sort on the web page to show the above mentioned progress.

Comment: you can use something like Log4Net to do Logging what type of logging are you currently using if any..?

Comment: Store the current completion percentage (or whatever data you want) in the `Session` and periodically make an Ajax request to the server to grab the percentage out of the `Session`.

Comment: You might look at SignalR and KnockoutJS to assist you with some of the ajax work. [Sample](http://www.iwantmymvc.com/mvc-3-signalr-knockout-real-time-notifications)

Comment: I would discourage you from using an actual progress bar and instead have a GIF (or whatever) showing that work is being done and perhaps a current step. Trying to figure out how long it's going to take, estimating that against the polling time of your ajax etc, just messy in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this even possible?

Yes, but it's not easy, or pretty.

> The best way I can think of to do this is to log progress to a file on the server and periodically read the file contents via Ajax/Javascript, but this seems like a kludge.

Yep, pretty much.  Other options are to use a database to store the info, or session, but any storage location that can be accessed somehow through an Ajax request would work.  You'll no doubt want to make a web service or similar to abstract away whatever storage method you use.

[Here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETBackgroundWorker-dda8d7b6/view/SourceCode) is an implementation of that general approach in a Microsoft example.  It uses Session to store the current progress, and relied heavily on ASP-based constructs.

Another avenue entirely would be to set up a websocket between the client and the server which would allow you to push information from the server to the client.  It would likely perform better (reduced network IO), although it may not be easier to set up.  I don't have any examples (or experience attempting) such a solution though.

Answer (score 0):

ajax , ajax , xhr, jsonp, with milestones in your process so you can give status

Answer (score 0):

If the process you are running is independent of your page (for example, a shell script inside a server), you can write the intermediate result of this script in a text file accessible by javascript (for example in http://contosoweb.com/web/log.txt), and update it periodically from the page using a timer and some jquery.

Here you have the info of .Ajax in the jQuery Docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

And here how to use a timer: [How to set a timer in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460474/how-to-set-a-timer-in-javascript)