# Timer instead of mouse events

Tags: html, function, timer, mouseevent, containers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set a timer in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460474/how-to-set-a-timer-in-javascript)

I added a container to my website. The container is a small form appearing and disappearing in mouse events like click or hover. How Can I control its behavior with timer?
For example if a small box appears can I make it to auto-hide after 5 seconds instead of clicking on it?

here is the function that I want to control with timer:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".button-slide").click(function(){
$(".feedback").slideToggle("slow");
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have you even tried to search before asking? There are probably thousands of posts regarding JavaScript timers here on SO.

Comment: I am not referring to javascript. I ask if there is a html function for setting timers to control other fucntions.

Comment: HTML doesn't have functions. It's a markup language, not a programming language.

Comment: Ok mea culpa.. but still getting involved with the Java script lg will mislead me since I don't know much... So  If you have any suggestions let me know.. I will read the post that you mentioned.