# Refresh image every minute using year, month, date, hour, sec format

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
<script language="javascript"> 

//Get Year, Month, Date, Hour and Minute to form Strings

    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var YY = y.toString();

    var m = today.getMonth()+1;
    if (m <= 9){
        m = '0' + m;
    }
    var MM = m.toString();

    var d = today.getDate();
    if (d <= 9){
        d = '0' +d;
    }
    var DD = d.toString();

    var h = today.getHours();
    if (h <= 9){
        h = '0' + h;
    }
    var HH = h.toString();

    var mi today.getMinutes();
    if (mi <=9){
        mi = '0' + mi;
    }
    var MiMi = mi.toString();

//Create image file in folder details, using year, month, date, hour and minute Strings
//Image file is in the /public_html folder, year+month+date sub-folder, hour sub-sub-folder,
// prefix with "tbmc_", year+month+date+hour+minutes in-between and ends with "59.jpg"  
// Assgin folder and image file details to a variable F 

    var F = "/public_html/"+YY+MM+DD+"/"+HH+"/tbmc_"+YY+MM+DD+"_"+HH+MiMi+"59.jpg";

//Try to print but nothing happen


<img scr= "F" width="1" height="1">

</script> 

</body>
```

Comment: what's the issue? what have you tried? what errors do you get? by "refresh the image" do you mean overwrite it or create a new one?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me but I think these links can help you http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460474/how-to-set-a-timer-in-javascript

Comment: My issue is with formatting of the string for IMG SRC, manage to get it correct with the following code, but have problem displaying the image using a variable ...

Comment: Why do you declare `img` tag inside `<script>` ? Shouldn't it be outside, in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your javascript:
I've added the following line at the beginning:

```
var today = new Date();
```

and corrected the line:

```
    var mi = today.getMinutes();
```

where the = was missing. Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/g1ut9n08/

```
//Get Year, Month, Date, Hour and Minute to form Strings
    var today = new Date();
    var y = today.getFullYear();
    var YY = y.toString();

    var m = today.getMonth()+1;
    if (m <= 9){
        m = '0' + m;
    }
    var MM = m.toString();

    var d = today.getDate();
    if (d <= 9){
        d = '0' +d;
    }
    var DD = d.toString();

    var h = today.getHours();
    if (h <= 9){
        h = '0' + h;
    }
    var HH = h.toString();

    var mi = today.getMinutes();
    if (mi <=9){
        mi = '0' + mi;
    }
    var MiMi = mi.toString();

//Create image file in folder details, using year, month, date, hour and minute Strings
//Image file is in the /public_html folder, year+month+date sub-folder, hour sub-sub-folder,
// prefix with "tbmc_", year+month+date+hour+minutes in-between and ends with "59.jpg"  
// Assgin folder and image file details to a variable F 

    var F = "/public_html/"+YY+MM+DD+"/"+HH+"/tbmc_"+YY+MM+DD+"_"+HH+MiMi+"59.jpg";

//Try to print but nothing happen

    alert(F);


        //Get Year, Month, Date, Hour and Minute to form Strings
        var today = new Date();
        var y = today.getFullYear();
        var YY = y.toString();

        var m = today.getMonth()+1;
        if (m <= 9){
            m = '0' + m;
        }
        var MM = m.toString();

        var d = today.getDate();
        if (d <= 9){
            d = '0' +d;
        }
        var DD = d.toString();

        var h = today.getHours();
        if (h <= 9){
            h = '0' + h;
        }
        var HH = h.toString();

        var mi = today.getMinutes();
        if (mi <=9){
            mi = '0' + mi;
        }
        var MiMi = mi.toString();

    //Create image file in folder details, using year, month, date, hour and minute Strings
    //Image file is in the /public_html folder, year+month+date sub-folder, hour sub-sub-folder,
    // prefix with "tbmc_", year+month+date+hour+minutes in-between and ends with "59.jpg"  
    // Assgin folder and image file details to a variable F 

        var F = "/public_html/"+YY+MM+DD+"/"+HH+"/tbmc_"+YY+MM+DD+"_"+HH+MiMi+"59.jpg";

    //Try to print but nothing happen

    alert(F);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function appendZero(input) {
    return input.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + input : input;
}

//Get Year, Month, Date, Hour and Minute to form Strings
var today = new Date();

var YY = today.getFullYear();
var MM = appendZero(today.getMonth()+1);
var DD = appendZero(today.getDate());
var HH = appendZero(today.getHours());
var MiMi = appendZero(today.getMinutes());

//Create image file in folder details, using year, month, date, hour and minute Strings
//Image file is in the /public_html folder, year+month+date sub-folder, hour sub-sub-folder,
// prefix with "tbmc_", year+month+date+hour+minutes in-between and ends with "59.jpg"  
// Assgin folder and image file details to a variable F 

var F = "/public_html/"+YY+MM+DD+"/"+HH+"/tbmc_"+YY+MM+DD+"_"+HH+MiMi+"59.jpg";

//Try to print but nothing happen

alert(F);
```